# invoke-expression doesnot throw an error in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am creating custom forms and adding it to the printer server properties using forms.vbs and running it through cmd. The script is as follows

```
cscript 'C:\Tools\forms.vbs' -a -n "DD" -u inches -h 7.48 -w 7.48 -t 0 -e 0 -b 7.48 -r 7.48
```

This works fine when running in command prompt.

Now I invoked this code to the powershell as follows and it also works fine

```
  $formname = "DD"
  $cmd = "cscript 'C:\Tools\forms.vbs' -a -n " + '"' + $formname + '"' + " -u inches -h 7.48 -w 7.48 -t 0 -e 0 -b 7.48 -r 7.48 "
  Invoke-Expression  $cmd
```

The issue started when I thought of checking the error handling thing for the powershell invoke expression.

In cmd when we give the expression as

```
cscript 'C:\Tools\forms.vbs' -a -n "DD" -u inches -h 7.48 -w 7.48 -t 0 -e 0 -b 0 -r 0
```

This will definitely throw error as per the notes given in the [form.vbs](http://www.seascapesailing.com/tools/_resource%20kit%20tools/Windows%20Resource%20Kits/Tools/forms.vbs) and it will not create a form.

So when I invoked the same error-thrown script to my powershell, the form is not creating as well as it is not throwing any errors. So I request me to guide in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoke-Expression only checks if it's possible to run the command at all. For example, if cscript.exe cannot be found, Invoke-Expression will throw an ObjectNotFound exception.

It doesn't check the exit code of the command or in any way parse its output. You should be able to see the output however.

Make sure you don't mix single and double quotes inside your expression:

```
$formname = "DD"
# Note double quotes around C:\Tools\forms.vbs
$cmd = 'cscript "C:\Tools\forms.vbs" -a -n ' + '"' + $formname + '"' `
    + ' -u inches -h 7.48 -w 7.48 -t 0 -e 0 -b 7.48 -r 7.48 '
Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

Output:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Unable to add form DD, error code: 0x1A8. Object required
```

If you want your code to throw an exception, you need to parse the output manually, e.g.:

```
try {
    $output = Invoke-Expression $cmd 
    if ($output -like "*error code*") { throw $output }
}
catch [System.Exception] {
    $message = ($Error[0].Exception -split [System.Environment]::NewLine)[-1]
    $message
}
```

Output:

```
Unable to add form DD, error code: 0x1A8. Object required
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, Thanks for the reply. The code to throw the exception is working fine. But still i am not getting any message for Invoke-expression $cmd.  like "Unable to add form, error code: 0X1A8".

Comment: In my code `$output` consumes Invoke-Expression output but then you can see it in the exception text. I tested it with PowerShell 2.0.

Comment: Am using version 4.0. Does that make any change?

Comment: Alexander, When I am running it in ISE, the error is showing up. But when I kept the script under a function and calling it(Powershell Windows Application-using Winforms), the error is not showing up

Comment: How can I segregate the out put based on the error?

Comment: I know little about Windows Forms but I added an example of how you can filter error message (essentially, the last line) in the `catch` block.

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander. Learnt a new thing.........I got the new way of handling the errors and segregate it. How I can update this answer in my question?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Start-Process to manage installs and uninstalls, and recently started using the same approach for arbitrary executables, which seems to be somewhat what you are trying to do, so...

```
$new.ExitCode > $null
$filepath = 'cscript.exe'
$argumentList = "C:\Forms.vbs"       
$exitCode = (Start-Process -FilePath:$filePath -argumentList:$argumentList -wait -errorAction:Stop -PassThru).ExitCode
$exitCode
```

The VBS just throws up a messagebox and quits with a return code, like so.

```
MsgBox "Text"
WScript.Quit 4
```

After I close the message box I get that 4 back at the PowerShell console. With no Wscript.Quit, or no exit code provided, I get the expected 0 back.
Simple example, but maybe gets you close, assuming you can get the error code you need into a variable so you can return it from the VBS. Or maybe someone points out some nuance I am not aware of and we both learn something. ;)